Update A-matrix of problem written with Linopy
I am trying to modify an already written problem in Linopy. First I extract the A-matrix of the constraints object (with model.constraints.to_matrix()), which I then modify, changing the parameters of all constraints. In the end I get a new modified A-matrix (saved as a scipy sparse csr matrix) as well as a row and a column scaling matrix (also scipy sparse csr matrices), with which I could modify the original A-matrix to get the new A-matrix.
I am now wondering what is the most efficient way to update the existing problem without having to completely re-construct it? Can I directly use the modified A-matrix or would it be more efficient to use the respective column and row scaling matrices? Do I need to iterate over all the constraint instances and manually change the data values, or is there a more advanced method already built into Linopy?
So far I am trying to iterate over all constraints, where I then overwrite the existing data/coefficients by reassigning new values through:
model.constraints[name].data = [list_of_new_coefficients].
However, it seems that the order of the extracted A-matrix (with model.constraints.to_matrix()) is different from the order of the values stored in "model.constraints[name].data".
Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
